# Why does $\lim\limits_{t\to-\infty}te^t=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Intuitively, $\lim\limits_{t\to -\infty}te^t=0$, since $e^t\to 0$ much faster than $t\to -\infty$.

Is there a way to more rigorously compute this? Writing it as $e^t/(1/t)$ seems resistant to l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Hint: what if you try writing it as a quotient in some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can definitely use [L'Hôpital's rule](http://quantizd.blogspot.com/p/definition-lhopitals-rule-states-that.html): $$\lim_{t\to-\infty}te^t=\lim_{t\to-\infty}\dfrac{t}{e^{-t}}=\lim_{t\to-\infty}\dfrac{1}{-e^{-t}}=0.$$

Comment: there's a wrong sign in the last limit

Comment: @user01123581321345589144... Thanks, fixed! ^^

Answer (score 3):

Set $x=-t$

$$\lim_{t\to -\infty}te^t=-\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=0$$

L'Hôpital's rule is not necessary

Comment: then why is the last limit equal to 0? Of course it is true,  but at this level it probably requires a justification...

Comment: you missed the point of my comment

Comment: @user01123581321345589144... Because $e^x$ grows much faster than $x$.

Comment: saying "grows much faster than" is not rigorous enough for a question at this level... I guess I'll just express my frustration downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid L'hopital's rule by noting by definition, $e^x = \sum_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Consider $\lim_{x \to \infty} x e^{-x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x}$.

Now, note for $x>0$ by definition of $e^x$, since all terms in the sum are non-negative, $e^x \geq 1+x+(1/2) x^2$ so $\frac{1}{1+x+(1/2)x^2} \geq \frac{1}{e^x}$. Multiplying both sides by $x$ preserves the inequality for $x>0$.

Clearly, since $\frac{x}{e^x} \geq 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x} \geq 0$ and $\frac{x}{1+x+(1/2)x^2} \geq \frac{x}{e^x}$ implies $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{1+x+(1/2)x^2}  \geq \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x} $. But the limit on the left hand side is $0$ (its linear/quadratic), so we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x} = 0$.