# Evaluate $xe^x$ when x tends to minus infinity.

Tags: limits

I came upon this question , I've got an answer as zero after drawing the graph

But I was told to use the L'Hopital's Rule to get the answer , using limits

Can someone please elucidate how to get the answer?

Thank you so much!

Comment: And did you try to use L'Hopital's Rule, as advised? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Why does $\lim\limits_{t\to-\infty}te^t=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767781/why-does-lim-limits-t-to-inftytet-0)

Comment: lasan.y:=-x, consider y goes to + infinity in the expression $-y/e^y$.Now use L'Hospital.

Comment: Oh this is intuitive , thank you sir @PeterSzilas

Answer (score 3):

Using L'Hopital is an overkill, but anyway:
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}xe^x=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}
$$
is a limit of type $\frac\infty\infty$, so L'Hopital gives
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac1{-e^{-x}}=0.
$$

Comment: Oh thank you so much sir / madam