# Limit of the series $a_n = ne^{-n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-without-lhopital

How do I find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = ne^{-n}$?

This is a question for real analysis, so I can not use L'Hôpital's.

I have this [similar limit here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767781/why-does-lim-limits-t-to-inftytet-0?noredirect=1&lq=1). But there is no rigorous proof. I know it is equal to zero. But I can not proof it using the definition of limit nor limit properties.

Comment: Can you use MathJax for your formulas? Maybe "an" is $a_n$ or $a^n$?

Comment: Did you mean: $$a_n=ne^{-\color{red}{n}}$$

Comment: Don't write "Find $\lim a_n=f(n)$" when you mean "define $a_n=f(n).$ Find $\lim a_n.$" The first is abuse of notation. If ou are wedded to that notation, write it as $$\lim (a_n:= f(n))$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $e^{-1}$ is just a constant, and as $n$ approaches infinity, just the $n$ term matters, so the limit tends to infinity. I think it won't be too difficult to prove using delta-epsilon.

Comment: It is likely they meant $ne^{-n}$

Comment: Sorry.. I get lost with mathjax. I indeed meant $a_n = ne^{-n}$

Comment: Actually, you need to solve this $\frac{n}{e^{n}}<\epsilon$ for $n$